# Slider en javascript no me carga al migrar web de hosting

Tags: javascript, div, slider, img

Este pequeño y básico slider funcionaba bien hasta que al migrar a un nuevo hosting ya no se ejecuta el javascript y carga todas las imágenes sin hacer el slider:

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#slider div:gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function(){
        $('#slider div:first-child').fadeOut(0)
         .next('div').fadeIn(0)
         .end().appendTo('#slider');}, 4000);
    });
 </script>

 <div id="slider">
        <div><a href="#"><img src="images/banner1.jpg" width="940" height="344" alt="banner img" /></a></div>
        <div><a href="#"><img src="images/banner1.jpg" width="940" height="344" alt="banner img" /></a></div>
        <div><a href="#"><img src="images/banner2.jpg" width="940" height="344" alt="banner img" /></a></div>
        <div><a href="#"><img src="images/banner3.jpg" width="940" height="344" alt="banner img" /></a></div>
        <div><a href="#"><img src="images/banner4.jpg" width="940" height="344" alt="banner img" /></a></div>
        <div><a href="#"><img src="images/banner5.jpg" width="940" height="344" alt="banner img" /></a></div>
        <div><a href="#"><img src="images/banner6.jpg" width="940" height="344" alt="banner img" /></a></div>
        <div><a href="#"><img src="images/banner7.jpg" width="940" height="344" alt="banner img" /></a></div>
        </div>
```

En la consola del navegador me da este error:
ReferenceError: $ is not defined

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: En la consola del navegador que error te da? un 404?

Comment: Este error: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: te falta el jquery

Comment: Ese error te da cuando no esta encontrando la libreria de jquery, en la consola del navegador no te muestra si la libreria del jquery te da 404?

Comment: añadida la libreria de jquery al código

Comment: Perfecto, voy a colocar mi respusta para que por favor me puedas puntuar, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según los comentarios el problma no eran las imagenes ya que te sale un error por la consola del navegador `error: ReferenceError: $ is not defined`, es error te da cuando no tines agregada la libreria de Jquery, agregala y seguramente se te solucionará.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Arreglado, era por el https que faltaba de la libreria del JQuery

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js
```

Gracias a todos!